# Can't install wine in Ubuntu

Tags: wine

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
[sudo] password for krishanu: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.3~groovy)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Are you installing from the Wine upstream repositories?

Comment: from here https://wiki.winehq.org/Download

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't install wine on ubuntu (actually lubuntu) 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205550/cant-install-wine-on-ubuntu-actually-lubuntu-18-04) and [Wine: How to fix held broken packages?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1126578/)

Comment: @KrishanuDev was Wine installed previously?  If so, do `sudo apt purge 'winehq-*' 'wine-*'` first, then attempt to install from scratch.  If that still doesn't work, then you need to contact WIneHQ upstream for support.

Comment: @Thomas Ward no bro it's the first time am installing wine

Answer (score 0):

This wine installation procedure was tested for gaming purposes and is running on Xubuntu 20.04 LTS machines.

a) Go to: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu for aditional information

b) Open the app Terminal and execute the following commands:
`su – administratoraccount` and password

c) Activate 32 bits architecture:
`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

d) Download repository key:
`wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key` and then `sudo apt-key add winehq.key`

e) Add the repository for ubuntu 20.04:

`sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'`

f) Update packages:
`sudo apt update`

g) Install the wine package suitable for the needs. Please, see Wine FAQ under the section **2.2 Which version of Wine should I use?** on https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Which_version_of_Wine_should_I_use.3F In this case the Development branch is used.

`sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-devel`

h) Install winetricks:
`sudo apt install winetricks`

i) Install dxvk package:
`sudo apt install dxvk`

**Note:**
Checking wine version installed: `wine --version`